# KeyListener not working when switching JPanels in a game

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener, keylistener

I'm working on a game, and when I switch from my MenuPanel to my actual game (Player), the KeyListener won't work, my character won't move. I implemented the KeyListener in both classes. How can I fix this problem? This is a snippet of the code for the game (Player), :

```
public class Player extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {


         private MijnProject mainVenster;

         public Player(MijnProject mainVenster) {

        this.mainVenster = mainVenster;
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true); 
        requestFocusInWindow();
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateTimerTask() , 0, PERIOD);
     }

         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up();
        }

        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down();
        }
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
        }
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();
        }
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            bullet();   

        }
```

And this is a part of the code for the menu (MenuPanel) :

```
public class MenuPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{

    private JButton playKnop, highScoreKnop, quitKnop;
    private MijnProject mainVenster;

    public MenuPanel(MijnProject mainVenster) 

    {   addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true); 
        this.mainVenster = mainVenster;

                playKnop = new JButton("Play");     
        playKnop.addActionListener(this);

        quitKnop = new JButton("Quit");
        quitKnop.addActionListener(this);

        highScoreKnop = new JButton("High Scores");
        highScoreKnop.addActionListener(this);

        this.add(playKnop);
        this.add(quitKnop);
        this.add(highScoreKnop);

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if (ae.getSource() == playKnop)
        {
            mainVenster.switchPanel(new Player(mainVenster));
        }

    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Try removing the KeyListener from the panel you are switching from and then adding it to the panel you are switching to.

Comment: That's what I initially did, and I just tried it again, but doesn't work... :(

Comment: Are you sure it's the listener that isn't working? It could be that the conditions aren't returning `true`, or maybe there's a flaw with the logic for movement. Could you confirm this?

Comment: I would suggest adding the KeyListener to the Frame or JFrame.  That way, you don't have to worry about any component switching.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. 2) `KeyListener` is a lower-level API that has many problems, for Swing, we'd typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). 3) Don't extend components or windows without good reason. There isn't one here, as far as I can see.